# How do I send secure cookies using node and a ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse (Httpd/Amazon linux)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, httpd, node.js, proxypass

I am still pretty new but I am using an Amazon linux image and httpd to encrypt and decrypt SSL requests. Then I Proxy those messages to and from a NodeJS app running on port 3001. To do this I have the following in my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
...
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://*IP*:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://*IP*:3001/
</VirtualHost>
```

The public site works great. However, when I try to set a secure cookie using the following...

> Error: Cannot send secure cookie over unencrypted connection

I set my cookie in node like this...

```
const CALLBACK = function(ctx, next) {
    ...
    ctx.cookies.set(
        COOKIE_NAME,
        response.data.id_token,
        {
          secure: true,
          domain: COOKIE_DOMAIN
        },
    );
}
```

I have also tried adding this to ssl.conf...

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

But it didn't help either, anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I found this in a question and it worked for me (although I can't find the question now)...

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
... 
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure
```

Then I just stopped setting it as secure in node and everything seems to work fine.